# How to have to two mappings to a struct?

Tags: solidity

I have a exchange type of use case in which the customer needs access to a centralised wallet based on different access methods (eg email, apikeys, actual wallet address). I tried mapping twice to the same struct and remix kicked out an error.

Here is the sample code -

```
struct ClientWallet {
    uint clientBalance;  
    bool clientAccountExists; 
    bytes32 apiKeyHash;
}



mapping (address => ClientWallet) public ClientWallets; // direct access
mapping (bytes32 => ClientWallet) public ClientWallets; // hash of email
```

I can code a workaround by using more structs and variables but this seems pointless. I tried mapping bytes32 to address and then to ClientWallet but that failed.

Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two variables with the same name (`ClientWallets`). If you give them different names, your code should compile. But note that the two mappings won't "point" to the same values. E.g. if you do:

```
mapping(address => ClientWallet) public ownerToWallet;
mapping(bytes32 => ClientWallet) public hashToWallet;

...

hashToWallet[something] = ownerToWallet[msg.sender];
```

you'll end up with two copies of the same struct. Modifying one won't affect the other.

What you likely want is something like this:

```
mapping(address => ClientWallet) public wallets;
mapping(bytes32 => address) public emailHashToAddress;

...

// e.g. to access a wallet by email hash
wallets[emailHashToAddress[hash]]
```

Comment: I was thinking of this type of construction. That is a good solution. If there is no mapping (ie email not mapped to the actual wallet) would the mapping return null? I had previously coded a bool to account for this in a struct. Therefore if we use a require and no struct would that code as - require(wallets[emailHashToAddress[hash]!=0x)?

Comment: Solidity doesn't have a `null`. You'd get the zero value of the struct, which means `clientBalance` and `apiKeyHash` are `0`s, and `clientAccountExists` is `false`.

Comment: So you probably want to keep `clientAccountExists` (unless one of the other fields can't be `0` for an existing client).

Comment: I used this -   require (emails[hashEmail] != address(0));